# DataTable is not working with table with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, datatable

Greetings am having an issue with Data table plugin, the issue is that am using fetchAPI to fetch data and through js am creating and appending cells and rows to the html table with this data but when i try to initialize the DataTable nothing happens i knew that this can be solved using delegation but i think i tried that and didn't work by binding an addEventListener to the parent element but nothing happened here is the code snippet

```
let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
  

//////////////
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Initialize DataTables
  new DataTable('#clients');
});

/////////////

async function fetchAllClients(){
  
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let table = document.querySelector('#clients');
    response = await fetch(`${url}customers`, {
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Accept": "application/json",
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
              },
          method: 'get',
      }); //
        let myData = await response.json();
        console.log(myData.data);

        // Loop through the JSON data
          for (const object of myData.data) {
            // Create a new row for the table
            const row = document.createElement("tr");
              // adding control buttons to the table
              const cellButton = document.createElement("td");
              const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
              removeButton.textContent = 'حذف';
              removeButton.className = 'btn btn-danger mt-3 format delete-btn';
              removeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
              // removeButton.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "modal");
              // removeButton.setAttribute("data-bs-target", "s");

              cellButton.appendChild(removeButton);

            // Add cells to the row for each property of the object
            for (const key in object) {
              const cell = document.createElement("td");
              cell.textContent = object[key];

              row.appendChild(cell);
              
            }

            // Append the remove button to the control cells 
            row.appendChild(cellButton);
            // Append the row to the table
            table.appendChild(row);
          }


    //   .catch(function(error) {
    //       console.log(error);
    //   });
};

fetchAllClients();
```

i included all the necessary links for the plugin and it shows up but it says no data when the documents loads although as i mentioned the rows are there